# Google+ Share link does not work with my Website

Tags: google-plus, facebook-opengraph, social-networking

i have a problem with sharing links of my website in Google+. So, if i want to share a link of my website (http://www.droidwiki.de/Hauptseite) G+ say, that the webpage can not be loaded. Same problem is with the Google +1 button on the page. If someone click this button, it appears a red exclamation mark. Sometimes, only the URL, but no opengraph data will show, but the most time, it only doesn't work. Other websites work perfectly with the account.

The same pages work without errors on facebook, will show the title of page and the opengraph description.

Have anybody the same problem, or a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any of the errors you're reporting.

While OpenGraph is supposed to work with Google's bot, it often doesn't work that well. Best practice is also to include schema.org microdata so Google's plus bot and search bot process it. See https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/ for details and http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets for a tool to help you test your markup.

Comment: Hello Prisoner, i think i must say, that i'm from germany, now i have connect to google plus with an US Proxy and the link share work like before. I have a similar problem, too, with the google oauth2. The third party icon does not show when i connect from germany, but, if i connect with an US proxy, all work fine :o